# Getting limited json response from server side nodejs to angularjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, json, node.js

I get this json response from node.js server.

I display this in my frontend using angularjs ng-repeat function.
When the response contains more than 100000 objects in the array, the browser hangs

So i want to get first **three objects in the array** response,

but again i am sending this response to server side back,

so i want to send all data.

My json response from server-side:

```
[ { 
  field5: 'Chennai',
  field6: 'Asia',
  field7: '600091',
  field8: '10-10-1996'},
{ 
  field5: 'Tamilnadu',
  field6: 'Asia',
  field7: '600091',
  field8: '10-10-1996' },
{ 
  field5: 'Tuticorin',
  field6: 'Asia',
  field7: '600091',
  field8: '10-10-1996' },
{ 
  field5: 'Japan',
  field6: 'Asia',
  field7: '600091',
  field8: '10-10-1996'},
{ 
  field5: 'China',
  field6: 'Asia',
  field7: '600091',
  field8: '10-10-1996' },
{ 
  field5: 'Canada',
  field6: 'Asia',
  field7: '600091',
  field8: '10-10-1996' },
{ 
  field5: 'Canada',
  field6: 'Asia',
  field7: '600091',
  field8: '10-10-1996'} ]
```

My controller.js :

Getting server side data to angularjs:

```
$http({
   method: 'GET',
   url: '/api/getnewgroup'
}).then(function (response) {
   $scope.excels = response.data;
}, function (response) {
   window.location.href = '/';
});
```

My last api sending data from client to server:

```
$scope.uploadLast = function () {
   var data = {
      excels: $scope.excels,
   };
   $http.post('/api/uploadlast', data).then(function (response) {
   }).catch(function (response) {
      alert(response.data);
      console.log(response);
   });
}
```

Comment: Your server already has the data (which it is sending to frontend). Why do you need to send it back from frontend? You can access the same data in the backend itself.

Comment: I am changing some form of stuffs, in my project and i am sending back, some form of edited object

Comment: Okay. In that case you need to use pagination. The user will be able to edit only the data that you show. So if you show 3 rows, send the updated 3 rows back and update the complete data in the backend.

Comment: Is this possible to do this using splice method? I am changing some form of stuffs means  i am just adding one object inside my json from client side , then i am sending that.

Answer (score 1):

In your ng-repeat you can use the "limitTo" filter, like so:

```
ng-repeat="excel in excels | limitTo:3"
```

This will only show the first 3 entries of the array.

If you want to have another array for the displayed items, you could try:

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/api/getnewgroup'
}).then(function (response) {
    $scope.excels = response.data.slice(0, 3);
    $scope.remainingExcels = response.data.slice(3);
}, function (response) {
    window.location.href = '/';
});
```

and

```
$scope.uploadLast = function () {
    var data = {
        excels: $scope.excels.concat($scope.remainingExcels),
    };
    $http.post('/api/uploadlast', data).then(function (response) {
    }).catch(function (response) {
        alert(response.data);
        console.log(response);
    });
}
```

But this is a very "ugly" thing to do.

Comment: Limit will just hide the json object in UI, but they getting almost all data from server side.

Comment: @MohamedSameer So be more clear about what you want to do, no need to downvote my answer. How do you expect to have *all* the data on the frontend without getting it from the backend? Your problem is not a javascript or angular related problem, but a backend one, then.

Comment: @MohamedSameer Edited it whit another suggestion.

Comment: @MohamedSameer If my suggestion worked, please don't forget to mark it as the accepted answer, to help future users with the same problem :)